# How to make pydev compile to .pyo and not .pyc

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I am using Eclipse with Pydev 1.5.7 installed. I am also using Python 2.5. By default, Pydev compiles to .pyc. How do I make it compile to .pyo by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can make pydev default to .pyo, but you can always pass "-O" as a VM argument in Run Configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Or add `PYTHONOPTIMIZE = 2` as environment variable in the run configuration dialog.